# StreamWriter висит и ничего не происходит

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

Вставляю данные в форму, отправляю POST запросом и они записываются в переменную модели типа string (проверил, переменная заполнена). Дальше отправляю на вход консольной программы таким образом

```
            Process mystem = new Process();
            test.StartInfo.FileName = "wwwroot/test.exe";          
            test.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            test.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            test.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;            
            test.Start();

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(test.StandardInput.BaseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(inputText);                           
            }
```

На этом этапе столкнулся с проблемой, на определенных данных `await writer.WriteLineAsync(inputText)` висит и ничего не происходит. Думал текст слишком большой, но нет, увеличил x5 текст который проходил нормально и проблем не возникло. Не понятно в чем дело, может какие-то символы не дают пройти.
Пример текста который проходит нормально:[Текст 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PIE0BI96sUfapOZ5a3-cZit52Kb7GFl3/view?usp=sharing)
Пример текста с которым не работает: [Текст 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ih7jm358wjjr_BG8p77QkbCrT7NLzkH2/view?usp=sharing)

Также пробовал вместо `WriteLineAsync` использовать просто `WriteAsync`, ничего не изменилось. В чем может быть причина и как ее выявить, если никаких ошибок не вылезает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это решило мою проблему:

```
inputText = inputText.Replace("\r", " ").Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\t", " ");
```